# Implementing handheld media rules in a style sheet

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

The below Web page should work correctly on desktop screens in Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Opera.  It does not work on my smartphone.  I've attempted to both attach a handheld media style sheet, and use @media rules within the screen style sheet, to solve the issues.  My smartphone still appears to be rendering the screen style sheet.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you very much.

http://nosgoth.net/NR-Test/ff_scroll-test9.html

Comment: Can you try putting all your handheld styles inside your screen stylesheet within a `@media` rule like: `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { /* your styles here... */ }`?

Comment: When I visited the site, I could not see any @media rules. I probably missed it, but if I were you I would use the developer tools in your browser to see if your mobile CSS is applied, but still overriden by your desktop CSS. If that's the case, it could be that your class/ID selectors in your mobile CSS are specific enough.

Comment: What phone is it? Also, your first stylesheet is used by any device, so maybe styles in there are used instead of your mobile version. I doubt using `@media handheld` will work. You probably want to use screensizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tested with Chrome, use the [device mode emulation tools in the Inspector](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) to help with determining if your stylesheets are being triggered or rendered correctly.

This should help a lot in trying to figure out the problem.